# How can I convert Digifinex websocket information to JSON?

Tags: python, json, utf-8, byte, decode

I'm getting information from Digifinex exchange Websocket:

```
from websocket import create_connection
ws = create_connection("wss://openapi.digifinex.com/ws/v1/")
ws.send('{"id":12312, "method":"ticker.subscribe", "params":["ETH_USDT", "BTC_USDT"]}')
print(ws.recv())
```

I have to get that info in JSON type like this:

```
{
    "error": null, 
    "result": 
    {
        "status": "success"
    },
    "id": 12312
}
```

But I can get like that:

```
b'x\xda\x04\xc0\xb1\r\xc4 \x0c\x85\xe1]\xfe\x9a\x06\xae\xf36\'B\x11\xc9J$?\xbbB\xec\x9eo\xb3"\xde\xc0\x9ero\xc4Ryb\x1b\xe5?K\x18\xaa9\x97\xc4i\xdc\x17\xd6\xc7\xaf\x8f\xf3\x05\x00\x00\xff\xff l\x12l'
```

decode('UTF-8'), decode('ascii'), decode('latin-1') not working

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://github.com/DigiFinex/api/blob/master/Websocket_API_en.md#url) you need to use `zlib deflate` to decode the message.

Answer (score 0):

```
 msg = zlib.decompress(ws.recv()).decode('utf-8')

 msg = json.loads(msg)
```

Comment: Hi Valentin, welcome to StackOverflow and thank you for your contribution! For your information, [a code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.